# Invalid product ID in iMessage application

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, imessage

**What I've done:**

1. I've created a new iMessage application, it came with two targets.
2. One for the iMessage extension (com.x.y.MessagesExtension) and one
   with the main bundle ID (com.x.y).
3. I've set up an app id for (com.x.y) and created an app on iTunes
   Connect.
4. I created an inApp purchase with id (foo) in iTunes Connect
5. I created a sandbox test user
6. I uploaded to test flight
7. **PROBLEM** Tried purchasing: Invalid Product ID

I've went through a nicely compiled list to make sure I wasn't missing anything from this source: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/

Everything checks out except for one; The bundle ID. I'm trying to purchase from the iMessages "extension", It has a different bundle Id than the one on iTunes Connect, but I figured since it's an extension, it should find the IAPs.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @RJiryes i got stuck also , my IAP is working in MAin app but is not in Imessage extention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Apple's great error messages, they were very descriptive when saying "Invalid Product Id". It turned out I didn't have my bank details active. Anyway, fixed that, and it solved my problem.